# Do I need to extract feature vectors from MNIST before using Kmeans

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, k-means, mnist

I am practicing with MNIST by `sklearn.cluster.KMeans`.

Intuitively, I just fit the training data to the sklearn function. But I have got pretty low accuracy. I am wondering what step I have missed. Should I extract feature vectors by PCA in the first place? Or should I change a bigger `n_clusters`?

```
from sklearn import cluster
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

clf = cluster.KMeans(init='k-means++', n_clusters=10, random_state=42)

clf.fit(X_train)

y_pred=clf.predict(X_test)

print(accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred))
```

I got poor `0.137` as result. Any recommendation? Thanks!

Comment: `KMeans` is a clustering algorithm, not exactly ideal for classifying images. You can try `KNeighborsClassifier` instead, along with other classification algorithms.

Answer (score 2):

How are you passing the images in? Are pixels flattened or kept in the 2d format?Are pixels being normalized to between 0-1?

As you are running clustering I would advise against PCA regardless and instead opt for T-SNE which keeps neighbourhood info but you should **not** need to do so before running K-Means.

The best way to debug is to see what your fitted model is predicting as the clusters. You can see an example here:
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/cluster/plot_kmeans_digits.html

With this info, you can get an idea of where mistakes might be. Good luck!

---

Adding a note: K-Means also probably is not the best model for your purposes. It's best for unsupervised contexts to cluster data. Whereas, MNIST is a classification usecase. KNN would be a better option while still allowing you to experiment with neighbours and such.

Here is an example I created with KNN: https://gist.github.com/andrew-x/0bb997b129647f3a7b7c0907b7e836fc

Comment: Thanks for your insight. I try KNN instead, and find a puzzling phenomenon. When I fitted the original 60,000 training samples to `sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier`, I got 0.15 or so accuracy in the test set with 10, 000 samples. Then I changed to the mini-MNIST offered by `sklearn` itself with about 1000 training samples and 100 test samples. I got a deceptive 0.99 or so accuracy. Considering the amount of samples, I don`t think that it is a reasonable result. ... ...

Comment: [cont] In the meantime, I am doing the same task with Deep Neural Network, and easily break through 98% accuracy with 60, 000 training samples. Do you think that KNN as a conventional method is to blame for the previously poor performance (0.15 accuracy) compared to Deep Neural Network with the same amount of data? Or is it something I mishandled?

Comment: I updated the answer with a gist link I created that uses KNN over MNIST. It was able to get about 98% on the test set. Hope it might help you debug your model.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm missing something: you are comparing clustering labels which are arbitrarily numbered 0-9, to labels which are unarbitrarily numbered 0-9. The 0s in your clustering might not end up in cluster number 0, yet this is the comparison you make. Clustering results are evaluated differently because of this. Some options to get a correct evaluation:

- Generate a [contingency matrix](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.cluster.contingency_matrix.html) and plot it
- Calculate the  [adjusted rand index](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.adjusted_rand_score.html)